# Convert .pb to .tflite for a model of variable input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, dataset

I was working on a problem where I trained a model using Tensorflow Object detection API using a custom dataset. I am using tf version 2.2.0

```
output_directory = 'inference_graph'
!python /content/models/research/object_detection/exporter_main_v2.py \
--trained_checkpoint_dir {model_dir} \
--output_directory {output_directory} \
--pipeline_config_path {pipeline_config_path}
```

I was able to get a .pb file successfully along with the .ckpt file. But now I need to convert it to .tflite. I am unable to do so, there is some error or another.

I tried the basic way which was written on TensorFlow documentation but that didn't work either.
Another code which I tried is below:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Input, Reshape, Concatenate, GlobalAveragePooling2D, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Activation, GlobalMaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence

model = tf.saved_model.load(f'/content/drive/MyDrive/FINAL DNET MODEL/inference_graph/saved_model/')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.post_training_quantize=True
converter.inference_type=tf.uint8
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("val_converted_model_int8.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

The error I am getting is:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 8 converter.post_training_quantize=True
> 9 converter.inference_type=tf.uint8
> ---> 10 tflite_model = converter.convert()
> 11 open("val_converted_model_int8.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py
> in convert(self)
> 837     # to None.
> 838     # Once we have better support for dynamic shapes, we can remove this.
> --> 839     if not isinstance(self._keras_model.call, _def_function.Function):
> 840       # Pass `keep_original_batch_size=True` will ensure that we get an input
> 841       # signature including the batch dimension specified by the user.
>
> AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'call'

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not about the variable input shape (while the error message is confusing).

`tf.saved_model.load` returns a `SavedModel`, but `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model` expects a Keras model so it couldn't handle it.

You need to use the [TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#from_saved_model) API. Something like this:

```
saved_model_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/FINAL DNET MODEL/inference_graph/saved_model/'
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
```

Let us know if you run into other issues.

Comment: The code ran without any errors, But no tflite file was saved. instead gave this warning: WARNING:absl:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D0_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_90785) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.

DO I need to write this file or anything? as there is no output. I have just working with tf models.

Comment: If you ran `model = converter.convert()` but it return an empty string with no error, it's likely a bug. Would you be able to file a Github issue with reproducible steps? Thanks!

Comment: I was talking about the code you gave : converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir).